# Prove that function $g(x \times y) = x + y^{2}$ is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

I got this result from a problem in Munkres, but I can't prove it directly (by the definition). Hope some one here can help me.

> > In space $R\times R$, consider a function $g(x \times y) = x + y^{2}$. Prove that $g$ is a quotient map in standard topology $R \times R$ and $R$.

Corresponding to function $g$, we've got a quotient topology $X^{*}$ consists of all parabols have forms $x + y^{2} = a$. Then we can build a bijective continuous function $f$ from $X^{*}$ to $R$. If we can prove $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $g$ is a quotient map. But I think there exists a direct way to prove this without using function $f$, for example, prove that $U $ is open in $R$ if and only if $g^{-1}(U)$ is open in $R^{2}$, but I can't find the any way.

Please help me solve this. Thanks.

Comment: That's a little bit of a mess of notation. Define $X^*$ explicitly - it is $X^*=(\mathbb R\times \mathbb R)/\sim$ for some equivalence relation $\sim$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:Yes, that's right. Thanks you. Sorry for not making the notion clear enough...

Comment: The function $g$ is clearly continuous and onto, so it is enough to show that $g$ is an open map. Since $g$ is $\mathcal C^1$ with $\nabla g(x,y)\neq 0$ at every point, this follows from the inverse function theorem.