# Show that $h(x,y)=x+y^2$ is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

The specific problem I am faced with is to show that $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, $h(x,y)=x+y^2$ is a quotient map. I tried to show that it is open map, but the $y^2$ seems to ruin this, and tried to show it is closed map but failed. I thought that maybe sum of closed maps is a closed map, but this doesn't appear to be the case. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Unanswered duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478163/prove-that-function-gx-times-y-x-y2-is-a-quotient-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U = V_1\times V_2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ be open. Then $h[U] = \bigcup_{y\in V_2} (y^2+V_1)$. Hence $h$ is open, continuous and surjective, so a quotient map.

Comment: I see, so you get around the issue of $y^2$ by considering intervals in $x$ and taking union over $y$. That's pretty clever. What if we considered $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$? This trick wouldn't work anymore, right?

Comment: @DavidRaveh the map $(x, y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$ will still be open by similar argument. If both open sets $V_1, V_2$ are intervals that contain $0$, then image of $V_1\times V_2$ is of the form $[0, a)$. If one of them doesn't, it will be of the form $(a, b)$.

Comment: I was just realizing this. I think I can formally separate x into 3 cases and use your trick to make it rigorous. Thanks for your help!